# Protractor Selenium Standalone server is getting timeout error

Tags: selenium, protractor

When I execute my test project I'm getting below error

```
node:70468) [DEP0022] DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use 
os.tmpdir() instead.
[15:07:12] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[15:07:12] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
[15:07:46] E/launcher - Error: Error: Timed out waiting for the WebDriver server at http://172.25.144.1:56412/wd/hub
    at onError (C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\workspace\xxx\Automation\xxx-automation\web\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\http\util.js:102:16)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
[15:07:46] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100
```

Protractor version: 5.1.2 and 
Selenium Standalone server 3.12.0

Comment: Can you add your config file details ?

Comment: Error is pretty clear & concise `os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use 
os.tmpdir() instead`

Comment: @DebanjanB, that is just a warning message. the actual error is different.

Comment: @Murthi But you got another error `Timed out waiting for the WebDriver server at http://172.25.144.1:56412/wd/hub`. Can you update the question with startup command for Selenium Server and the trace logs?

Comment: @DebanjanB I am not OP for this question.

Comment: @Murthi my bad :) possibly OP reads the same lines to update the question

Comment: @demouser123 Please click on the URL for the protractor conf file : https://docs.google.com/document/d/143vO2VFDYjEZHTTL84O_wyOeFpC0OoGmEy8hjtlDJwA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was selenium standalone server automatically setting up a random host from their store to start up the selinum web driver. 
In this case the connected server was not responding to the client.
Then I connected to a different network and re-build the project it chnaged the selenium server host.

```
Selenium standalone server started at http://10.0.75.1:64132/wd/hub
```

It fixed the issue..

Thanks for the support....